# Looking for good software for ebook management

Tags: pdf, cross-platform, pdf-viewer, ebooks

I am looking for a software like Calibre that could manage my ebook library. Here are some features that I really need, some of them are not available from Calibre.

1. Allow multiple clients access the library at the same time, either from cloud drives or built-in features. For built-in features, it should work without configuring router forwarding to handle external access.
2. Allow adding books while some clients are reading. Calibre falls short on this one.
3. Allow hierarchical categories/tag.
4. Allow access from win7/win10/MacOS/
5. Allow pdf format. Would be great if support djvu and epub as well.

Above features are what we need to share a library with our research team. I think it would be helpful to other groups, too.

Comment: "should work without configuring router forwarding to handle external access": That would mean cloud-hosted – as unless your computer is directly connected to the internet without a router between, this IMHO is technically impossible *unless the application can reconfigure the router itself* – which I'd rather think dangerous. // Apart from that, [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/) could fit. Not using it myself, so i cannot say for sure, but worth a look. See [here](/search?q=mendeley) for other answers with Mendeley.